# Confusion about the para indexPath of cellForRowAtIndexPath in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm new to iOS dev so this might be a simple question to you but I check the apple dev guide just could not find it.

I have many UITableViews using one dataSourceDelegate,this is how I create them：

```
- (void)createSomeTableview:(NSInteger)numberOfTableViews{

    tableViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numberOfTableViews];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTableViews; i++) {
        UITableView *itemTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 0, 235, self.view.bounds.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [itemTableView setDataSource:self];
    [itemTableView setDelegate:self];

    [itemTableView registerClass:[KKYItemListCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)currentSection]];
    [tableViewsArray addObject:itemTableView];

    [[self view] addSubview:itemTableView];
    }
}
```

I call `createSomeTableview` when I finish got my data back from my server,then I use a cycle to reload the data of each tableView (I call this in a block of AFNetwoking POST after got the response successfully):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sectionNum;i++){
        currentSection = i;
        [[tableViewsArray objectAtIndex:i] reloadData];
    }
```

This is where the disaster came!(T T)There is always a null cell return from the reloading process so I track the reloading process and found a strange thing:

Once I call the method `reloadData`,the method `numberOfRowsInSection` is called (I have just one section for each table),after this then go back to call the `reloadData` of the next Tableview in `tableViewsArray`.(I used to think the `reloadData` will call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` next).

After all the views in `tableViewsArray` calling `numberOfRowsInSection`,the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` had been called by the last view in `tableViewsArray`.Well that's fine,it starts to build the data for my tableview~,I do this to specify my tableViews in array:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    .....
    if (tableView == sectionTableView) {
        ...
    } else if (tableView == [tableViewsArray objectAtIndex:(long)currentSection]) {
        ...//data handle
        if (itemsNum == 0) { //itemsNum is the count of current table's items
            currentSection--; //if loaded end then go to the next tableView
            return cell;
        }
        itemsNum--;
        return cell;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But something wrong with it!!! I got 18 items in the current data from server (itemsNum = 18),and I did get 18 return from `numberOfRowsInSection`.But when the `indexPath.row == 6`,the tableView's index is `currentSection - 1`,which means it's no longer the current tableView (actually it was the next tableView)is calling the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath'.

So `(tableView == [tableViewsArray objectAtIndex:(long)currentSection])` is false,method return a nil cell,then crashed.

I'm wondering where does the method 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath' get the para row in indexPath?Isn't the return of 'numberOfRowsInSection'?(not seemed like in my program).

Comment: Can you change the name `itemTableViewController` to `itemTableView`? A table view controller is different from a table view.

Comment: oops,I corrected them.Thanks for mention~@AdamPro13

Comment: It is not clear to me why you have this `currentSection` or why you decrement it in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. It looks like you're making assumptions about the order in which that method will be called rather than checking the section of the provided index path. That seems like an incredibly fragile and error prone way for a data source to produce cells.

Comment: In fact there is a one-to-many relationship between `sectionTableView`   and tableviews in tableViewsArray.The structure of data I request is just like this:{"data":[  {  "section":"Food","items":[{...}]  }  ]} @Jonah

Comment: there will be many items in array `items`,and these items are under the `section`,so I can select the row in `sectionTableView` to show the data in the other table `itemTableView` in one page.@Jonah